# Why does Wolfram Alpha give a wrong answer to a linear ODE with constant coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, wolfram-alpha

This is very odd as it is a really simple ODE and the interpretation of the input seems correct, yet Wolfram Alpha produces rubbish:
$$x'' - 2x' + x = t, \quad x(0) = 1.$$
Wolfram Alpha claims that the solution to this is $x(t) = c_1e^tt$ ([Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%27%20-%202x%27%20%2B%20x%20%3D%20t%2C%20x%280%29%20%3D%201)). For reference, it gets it correct if you either put none or two initial conditions ([Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%27%20-%202x%27%20%2B%20x%20%3D%20t),[Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%27%20-%202x%27%20%2B%20x%20%3D%20t%2C%20x%280%29%20%3D%201%2C%20x%27%280%29%20%3D%200)). Is this a known issue?

Comment: This is just a bug in parsing the natural language input. Mathematica has no problem solving it  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9niX.png) . It is better to ask this at Wolfram community site than here.

Comment: @Nasser The parsed input seems correct though. Looks like just a bug.

Comment: (1) When no Initial Condition is given , Wolfram will itself use 2 Constants. (2) When 2 Initial Conditions are given , Wolfram will use those 2 Constants. **(3) When 1 Initial Condition is given , Wolfram gets confused & uses 1 unknown (Default?) Initial Condition to generate generally wrong answer. (4) Instead , user should give 2 unknowns to generate correct answer [[ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%27+-+2x%27+%2B+x+%3D+t%2C+x%280%29+%3D+A%2C+x%27%280%29+%3D+B ]]** (5) It is a Bug & Wolfram team should be notified to check & respond & fix.

Comment: @Nasser: The input seems to be parsed correctly. If you click on the "Step-by-step solution" button, you can see the beginning of a correct solution for the correct problem. Perhaps someone with a Pro account could look at the full step-by-step solution to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Missed this in my earlier comment : (6) In order to avoid confusing Wolfram & triggering that Bug , user should give 1 known Initial Condition ($A=1$) & leave the other Initial Condition $B$ unknown [[ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%27+-+2x%27+%2B+x+%3D+t%2C+x%280%29+%3D+1%2C+x%27%280%29+%3D+B ]] to generate correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Perhaps someone with a Pro account could look at the full step-by-step
> solution to see where it goes wrong.

There is nothing wrong with step-by-step. It gives correct solution. This could be just a final display bug where it did not format the answer correctly on the screen.

Here is the step-by-step solution from Wolfram alpha. If you have Mathematica, no need for PRO account. As one can issue the Wolfram alpha command from inside Mathematica and get the step-by-step solution that way. Now, clicking on the button there which says "step-by-step" gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So you see, it does solve it correctly. But the final output where it says "Differential equation solutions" is not the same as the final answer in the step-by-step. So looks like a software bug in final display of solution.

I think this question is better posted at [Wolfram community](https://community.wolfram.com/) where Wolfram developers can more easily see it and fix the bug.